# PassportJS with facebook strategy left pending request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js

I am using Facebook strategy with nodejs and typescript and react with javascript.
I am using Render.com as host platform on Nodejs and vercel for ReactJS.

The steps I completed:
I created a function that will detect wether the app is in production or development:

```
export const getProductionURL = (endpoint?: string): string => {
    const baseURL = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'https://car-share.vercel.app' : 'http://localhost:3001';
    
    if (endpoint) return `${baseURL}${endpoint}`;
    else return baseURL; 
}


export const getProductionURLServerAuth = (endpoint?: string): string => {
    const baseURL = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'https://car-ride-backend.onrender.com' : 'http://localhost:3000';
    
    if (endpoint) return `${baseURL}${endpoint}`;
    else return baseURL; 
}
```

Here, the first function is used for CORS (frontend accept) and the second function (`getProductionURLServerAuth` ) is used for backend.

The second step was to create the strategy. In the passport config I build the facebook strategy where I used the credentials, and the function for the dynamic backend URL:

```
// Facebook config
passport.use(
  new FacebookStrategy({ 
      clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK__ID || '',
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK__SECRET || '',
      callbackURL: getProductionURLServerAuth('/auth/facebook/callback'), 
      state: true,
      
      profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'photos', 'email'] // Specify the profile fields you want to access
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      console.log(profile._json);
      
}
));
```

The user routes jhust call the route using `/auth/facebook`

```
  /**
   *      Facebook user route
  */
 userRouter.get('/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: ['public_profile']}));
 userRouter.get('/facebook/callback',
   passport.authenticate('facebook', { 
    failureRedirect: getProductionURL('/login'), 
    failureMessage: true, 
    successRedirect: getProductionURL('/profile') }),
   (req, res) => res.redirect(getProductionURL('/profile')));
```

Here, i used `getProductionURL` to use the frontend links, because I want to redirect to the profile page if succeeded.

The app.ts simply uses the `app.use('/auth', userRouter);`
So, if the server is in development, the link for the auth would be `http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook` or `http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback`

Thirdly, In the meta developers account I used the following config:
[image]

The frontend is soo simple:

```
const Login = () => {
  
  
  const handleGoogleLogin = () => window.open(getProductionURL('/auth/google'), '_self');
  const handleFacebookLog = () => window.open(getProductionURL('/auth/facebook'), '_self');
  
  return (
    <main>

      <div className='w-[150px]'>
        <ButtonIcon 
        onClickFunction={handleGoogleLogin}
        icon={
          <AiOutlineGoogle color='black' size={25}/>
        }>Google</ButtonIcon>
      </div>


        <ButtonIcon 
        onClickFunction={handleFacebookLog}
        icon={
          <AiOutlineGoogle color='black' size={25}/>
        }>Facebook</ButtonIcon>


    </main>
  )
}

export default Login
```

I understand that in the development, we cannot use http. only enforced https. So cannot check this in development. However, when login in production, I successfully see the user details from facebook in the render.com console. What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks